# EF Core - Como mapear um campo de uma tabela que se relaciona com dois campos de outra tabela

Tags: c#

Tenho uma classe Pessoa (Campo PessoaId) que se relaciona com a classe PessoaContaBancaria (Campos: PessoaContaBancariaId, ContaBancariaTipo, PessoaId e PessoaBancoId).

Lógica: Na tabela Pessoa as pessoas físicas e jurídicas ficarão armazenadas com Ids distintos:

Ex:

1 - Pedro*

2 - Maria*

3 - Banco Santander

4 - Banco do Brasil

5 - Sicoob

Digamos, que na tabela PessoaContaBancaria, eu precise guardar uma conta da Maria cujo banco é Sicoo... então, o campo PessoaId da tabela Pessoa deveverá se relacionar com os campos PessoaId e PessoaBancoId da tabela PessoaContaBancaria...

Ex:

PessoaContaBancariaId = 1

PessoaId = 2 (Maria)

PessoaBancoId = 5 (Sicoob)

Como faço isso usando o Entity Framework Core? Segue meu código atual:

```js
 public class Pessoa
    {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaTipoId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaSituacaoId { get; set; }

        public virtual PessoaTipo PessoaTipo { get; set; }        
        public virtual ICollection<PessoaContaBancaria> PessoaContasBancarias { get; set; }
    }
```

```js
public class PessoaContaBancaria
    {
        public int PessoaContaBancariaId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }    
        public int PessoaBancoId { get; set; }
        public string Agencia { get; set; }
        public string NumeroConta { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }
        public bool Sistema { get; set; }

        public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    }
```

```js
public void PessoaContaBancariaMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaContaBancaria>()
                .ToTable("tblPessoaContaBancaria");

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaContaBancaria>()
                .HasKey(p => new { p.PessoaContaBancariaId, p.PessoaId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaContaBancaria>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Pessoa)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoaContasBancarias)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaId)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaContaBancaria>()
               .Property(p => p.Agencia)
               .HasColumnName("Agencia")
               .HasColumnType("Varchar(15)")
               .HasMaxLength(15)
               .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaContaBancaria>()
               .Property(p => p.NumeroConta)
               .HasColumnName("NumeroConta")
               .HasColumnType("Varchar(15)")
               .HasMaxLength(15)
               .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaContaBancaria>()
                .Property(p => p.DataInclusao)
                .HasColumnName("DataInclusao")
                .HasColumnType("DateTime")
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaContaBancaria>()
                .Property(p => p.Sistema)
                .HasColumnName("Sistema")
                .HasColumnType("Bit")
                .IsRequired();
        }
```

Comment: Deixa eu entender, você quer referenciar dois valores de uma unica entidade/classe ou cada valor uma entidade/classe diferente?

Comment: Seria "cada valor uma entidade/classe diferente", pois Um valor seria para a pessoa e outro para a pessoa que for definida como Banco.

Comment: Então você quer referenciar dois id's de de uma mesma classe(pessoa), que representa tanto uma pessoa física e jurídica. Eu iria separar isso em duas entidades e herdaria de uma classe pessoa em comum. Mas tenta referenciar dois id's no mapeamento. Primeiro na entidade PessoaContaBancaria, coloca mais um atributo do tipo pessoa: "Pessoa PessoaBanco". Já que você quer relacionar duas pessoas, em uma mesma entidade. Por fim referencie mais uma chave estrangeira de pessoa no mapeamento, representando PessoaBanco que acabamos de usar. Não testei porque estou sem ambiente aqui, mas tente e me fale.

Comment: Na vdd é tenho duas classes PessoaFisica e PessoaJuridica que estão relacionadas à Pessoa. Elas fazem essa Classificação... Eu segui sua sugestão: Criei uma propriedade PESSOABANCO  na classe Pessoa e mapeei assim: modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaContaBancaria>()
                .HasOne(p => p.PessoaBanco)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoaContasBancarias)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaBancoId)
                .IsRequired();

Comment: Infelizmente no powershel no Package Manager Console apresenta o erro: Cannot create a relationship between 'Pessoa.PessoaContasBancarias' and 'PessoaContaBancaria.PessoaBanco', because there already is a relationship between 'Pessoa.PessoaContasBancarias' and 'PessoaContaBancaria.Pessoa'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

Comment: Acredito que ele esteja fazendo confusão com o primeiro relacionamento usando a propriedade de navegação PESSOA que fará um relacionamento igual, mas para mapear a Pessoa....

Comment: Só corrigindo: eu criei uma propriedade PESSOABANCO na classe PessoaContaBancaria e não na classe Pessoa conforme eu disse no primeiro comentário.

Comment: Atualiza a pergunta com o estado atual, ate com as classes.  Obs: Por PessoaContaBancaria ter muitas pessoas, ela tem que estar referenciada como coleção na classe PessoaContaBancaria:  ICollection<Pessoa> PessoaFisica  e ICollection<Pessoa> PessoaBanco.